# Extracting the detected objects from image by PILLOW library

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, object-detection

the code below is to detect the objects in images. The code can detect the objects, count the number of detected objects, drawing rectangles to label the objects. Is there any way to extract and save each detected objects? For example; if there are 20 objects detected in an image, I would like to extract and save these 20 objects seperately. I would be appreciated for any help..

```
from PIL import Image

class TheOutliner(object):
    ''' takes a dict of xy points and
    draws a rectangle around them '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.outlineColor = 255, 0, 0
        self.pic = None
        self.picn = None
        self.minX = 0
        self.minY = 0
        self.maxX = 0
        self.maxY = 0
    def doEverything(self, imgPath, dictPoints, theoutfile):
        self.loadImage(imgPath)
        self.loadBrightPoints(dictPoints)
        self.drawBox()
        self.saveImg(theoutfile)

    def loadImage(self, imgPath):
        self.pic = Image.open(imgPath)
        self.picn = self.pic.load()

    def loadBrightPoints(self, dictPoints):
        '''iterate through all points and

        gather max/min x/y '''


        # an x from the pool (the max/min
        #   must be from dictPoints)
        self.minX = dictPoints.keys()[0][0]
        self.maxX = self.minX
        self.minY = dictPoints.keys()[0][1]
        self.maxY = self.minY


        for point in dictPoints.keys():
            if point[0] < self.minX:
                self.minX = point[0]
            elif point[0] > self.maxX:
                self.maxX = point[0]

            if point[1]< self.minY:
                self.minY = point[1]
            elif point[1] > self.maxY:
                self.maxY = point[1]
    def drawBox(self):
        # drop box around bright points

        for x in xrange(self.minX, self.maxX):
            # top bar
            self.picn[x, self.minY] = self.outlineColor
            # bottom bar
            self.picn[x, self.maxY] = self.outlineColor
        for y in xrange(self.minY, self.maxY):
            # left bar

            self.picn[self.minX, y] = self.outlineColor
            # right bar
            self.picn[self.maxX, y] = self.outlineColor
     def saveImg(self, theoutfile):
         self.pic.save(theoutfile, "JPEG")


class ObjectDetector(object):
    ''' returns a list of dicts representing 
        all the objects in the image '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.detail = 4
        self.objects = []
        self.size = 1000
        self.no = 255
        self.close = 100
        self.pic = None
        self.picn = None
        self.brightDict = {}
    def loadImage(self, imgPath):
        self.pic = Image.open(imgPath)
        self.picn = self.pic.load()
        self.picSize = self.pic.size
        self.detail = (self.picSize[0] + self.picSize[1])/2000
        self.size = (self.picSize[0] + self.picSize[1])/8
        # each must be at least 1 -- and the larger

        #   the self.detail is the faster the analyzation will be
        self.detail += 1
        self.size += 1

    def getSurroundingPoints(self, xy):
        ''' returns list of adjoining point '''
        x = xy[0]
        y = xy[1]
        plist = (
            (x-self.detail, y-self.detail), (x, y-self.detail), 
            (x+self.detail, y-self.detail),
            (x-self.detail, y),(x+self.detail, y),
            (x-self.detail, y+self.detail),(x, y+self.detail),
            (x+self.detail,y+self.detail)
            )
        return (plist)

    def getRGBFor(self, x, y):
        try:
            return self.picn[x,y]
        except IndexError as e:
            return 255,255,255

    def readyToBeEvaluated(self, xy):
        try:
            r,g,b = self.picn[xy[0],xy[1]]
            if r==255 and g==255 and b==255:
                return False
        except:
            return False
        return True

    def markEvaluated(self, xy):
        try:
            self.picn[xy[0],xy[1]] = self.no, self.no, self.no
        except:
            pass

    def collectAllObjectPoints(self):
        for x in xrange(self.pic.size[0]):
            if x % self.detail == 0:
                for y in xrange(self.pic.size[1]):
                    if y % self.detail == 0:
                        r,g,b = self.picn[x,y]
                        if r == self.no and \
                            g == self.no and \
                            b == self.no:
                            # then no more

                            pass
                        else:
                            ol = {}
                            ol[x,y] = "go"
                            pp = []
                            pp.append((x,y))
                            stillLooking = True
                            while stillLooking:
                                if len(pp) > 0:
                                    xe, ye = pp.pop()
                                    # look for adjoining points

                                    for p in 
                                    self.getSurroundingPoints((xe,ye)

                                        if self.readyToBeEvaluated((p[0], 
                                        p[1])):
                                            r2,g2,b2 = self.getRGBFor(p[0], 
                                            p[1])
                                            if abs(r-r2) < self.close and \
                                                abs(g-g2) < self.close and \
                                                abs(b-b2) < self.close:
                                                # then its close enough

                                                ol[p[0],p[1]] = "go"
                                                pp.append((p[0],p[1]))

                                            self.markEvaluated((p[0],p[1]))
                                        self.markEvaluated((xe,ye))
                                else:
                                    # done expanding that point
                                    stillLooking = False
                                    if len(ol) > self.size:
                                    self.objects.append(ol)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Start Process";

    # assumes that the .jpg files are in
    #   working directory 
    theFile = "new2"

    theOutFile = "new2.output"

    import os
    os.listdir('.')
    for f in os.listdir('.'):
       if f.find(".jpg") > 0:
            theFile = f
            print "working on " + theFile + "..."

            theOutFile = theFile + ".out.jpg"
            bbb = ObjectDetector()
            bbb.loadImage(theFile)
            print "     analyzing.."
            print "     file dimensions: " + str(bbb.picSize)
            print "        this files object weight: " + str(bbb.size)
            print "        this files analyzation detail: " + 
            str(bbb.detail)
            bbb.collectAllObjectPoints()
            print "     objects detected: " +str(len(bbb.objects))
            drawer = TheOutliner()
            print "     loading and drawing rectangles.."

            drawer.loadImage(theFile)
            for o in bbb.objects:
                drawer.loadBrightPoints(o)
                drawer.drawBox()

            print "saving image..."
            drawer.saveImg(theOutFile)

            print "Process complete"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `crop()` method :

add new method after `drawBox()`:

```
def saveBox(self,filename):
    # Create Box
    box = (self.minX, self.minY, self.maxX, self.maxY)

    # Crop Image
    self.pic.crop(box).save(filename)
```

change the main code :

```
        drawer.loadImage(theFile)
        idBox=0
        for o in bbb.objects:
            drawer.loadBrightPoints(o)
            drawer.drawBox()
            idBox=idBox+1
            drawer.saveBox("box_"+str(idBox)+"_"+theOutFile)

        print "saving image..."
        drawer.saveImg(theOutFile)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! When I change picture to self.pic and convert idBox to str, it works very well..

Comment: Since I am new, I have less than 15 reputations which prevents me to upvote :(  If I could I would upvote 100 times :))